# Is it possible to hold a spell cast from a spell scroll by Readying it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, readied-action

The rules for the [Ready](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Ready) action say:

> When you ready a spell, you cast it as normal but hold its energy, which you release with your reaction when the trigger occurs.

So, can this apply to a spell cast from a [spell scroll](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/spell-scroll)? Can I cast a spell from a scroll and hold it in the way mentioned about, releasing the spell on the meeting of the proper trigger condition?

[This question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/97356/how-does-using-a-scroll-function-when-using-the-ready-action) is very related, but only asks about the possibility of reading the scroll using the readied action (or starting to read it), but does not address the possibility of fully casting it like a normal spell and then releasing it using a trigger like a normal Readied Spell.

Comment: Related links: [Casting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/spellcasting#CastingaSpell), [Activating an item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/magic-items#ActivatinganItem)

Answer (score 10):

### Using an action to use the scroll encompasses both reading and casting it.

This is not a Cast A Spell action being readied, it is an Activate a Scroll action being readied.

Therefore, it's not subject to the concentration requirement imposed by the special readying rules for Casting A Spell.

This means that you can Ready an action to Activate a Scroll in response to <Trigger>, and it will allow you to make the cast just like readying a Cast A Spell action does. However, the spell doesn't occupy the concentration slot while you await the trigger and is cast all in one go.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83505/discussion-on-answer-by-axoren-is-it-possible-to-hold-a-spell-cast-from-a-spell).